# Execute a method right after Eureka client registers in Eureka Server

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

I want to execute a method once the Eureka Client registers in Eureka Server. I have written the below code but the code inside onApplicationEvent() method is not getting executed after Client registers in Eureka Server. But the application is getting registered in Eureka Server.

I have followed the below url and tried but it didn't work.

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/1679

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.xxx.network.inventory.oss.staticcontent", "com.xxx.commons.rest*"},
excludeFilters={
          @ComponentScan.Filter(type=FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value=RestTemplateConfig.class)})
@EnableEurekaClient
public class OssUiApplication implements ApplicationListener<EurekaInstanceRegisteredEvent> {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(OssUiApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(EurekaInstanceRegisteredEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Got it...");
    }
}
```

Please help me to execute a method just after the Client gets registered in Eureka server.

Comment: I have now resolved it .

Comment: implement  ApplicationListener (without Generic) to a Component annoted class and then do the below...

@Override
 public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEvent applicationEvent) {
  if (applicationEvent instanceof InstanceRegisteredEvent) {
   logger.info("InstanceRegisteredEvent listner called");
                  }
            }